# How to show prices as million and thousands format?

Tags: php

I have the following prices.

- 14,500,000
- 1,800,000

How these prices can be shown as millions and thousands in PHP ?

I want to have a user defined function to show these values as millions and thousands format as these prices will be dynamic.

**Updated**

I want to show the above values as:

1. 14,500,000 will be as 14 millions and 500 thounsands
2. 1,800,000 will be as 1 million and 800 thounsands.

So anyone can tell me how it can done so ?

Thanks.

Comment: What output do you expect? You somehow forgot to tell. Something like 14.5 million?

Comment: Do you always have amounts in the millions? If so, just divide by one million (that's your millions) and take the modulo one million then divide by 1000 (that's your thousands)

Comment: I dont need this in number format. It is already in number format. I have updated my question please see my question again. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$price = '14,500,000';

echo $price = (int)str_replace(",","",$price);
echo '<br>';

$thousands = $price % 1000000;

$millions = ($price - $thousands)/1000000;

$thousands = $thousands / 1000;
echo $thousands = $thousands . " Thousands";

echo $millions = $millions . " Millions";
```

Comment: for 14,000,000 output is: 0 Thousands14 Millions Which is not good aproach. My solution fix this :)

Answer (score 19):

Use [`number_format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) function

```
echo number_format("14500000", 0, '', ',');
```

**Output**

```
14,500,000
```

**OR**

If you want to represent price in Kilo/Million/Billion

```
$number = "14500000";

if ($number < 1000000) {
    // Anything less than a million
    $format = number_format($number);
} else if ($number < 1000000000) {
    // Anything less than a billion
    $format = number_format($number / 1000000, 2) . 'M';
} else {
    // At least a billion
    $format = number_format($number / 1000000000, 2) . 'B';
}

echo $format;
```

**Output**

```
14.50M
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [`number_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) function

```
number_format($number, 2, '.', ',');
```

**Full example:**

```
$number = '14,500,400';
$tab = explode(",",$number);
$arrayNumber = array_reverse($tab);
if(intval($arrayNumber[0])!=0){
    $str[] = $arrayNumber[0] . ' hundreds';
}
if(intval($arrayNumber[1])!=0){
    $str[] = $arrayNumber[1] . ' thousands';
}
if(intval($arrayNumber[2])!=0){
    $str[] = $arrayNumber[2] . ' millions';
}
$strArr = array_reverse($str);
echo join(' ', $strArr);
```

**[WORKING CODE](http://codepad.org/rViardI9)**

Comment: this starts with a string, not the integer

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `number_format` function stated at : http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Answer (score 0):

If you google for `php number thousand separator` the first result will point to the PHP docs describing [`number_format`](http://php.net/number_format)

> If only one parameter is given, **number** will be formatted without decimals, but with a comma (",") between every group of thousands.

Sample code:

```
$formatted_number = number_format(14500000);
```

---

If however, you want to display `14 million`, you can write a function that calculates the logarithm base 10 of the number (gives you the number of digits) and then have a lookup table with units (thousands, millions, etc.). Divide the number by the nearest multiple of 1000. This should give you your expected reuslt.

If your numbers are always in the millions range, it's simple division and modulo:

```
define('MILLION', 1000000);
$number = 14500000;

$millions = floor($number/MILLION);
$thousands = floor(($number % MILLION) / 1000);
$formatted = sprintf('%d millions and %d thousands', $millions, $thousands);
```