# How to show values in millions or billions in Drupal views

Tags: view, field, drupal-8, display

I am trying to display values of field "Contract Value" in millions as some stored values is 9 digit figures. For the convenience of users, I want display to these in million. This is very simple and common requirement for any application related to financial work. Please suggest easy solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do follwoing:

1. create custom field formatter example:
   https://www.drupal.org/docs/creating-custom-modules/creating-custom-field-types-widgets-and-formatters/create-a-custom-field-formatter
   and then you can write you own code
2. Write number conversion in above field formatter. example: [How to show prices as million and thousands format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19264374/how-to-show-prices-as-million-and-thousands-format)
3. Choose this field formatter in view.